# Redirecting "page.php/page.php" to normal page.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Some people leave the wrong type of links to the site, example:

```
https://example.com/subdir/3.php/3.php
```

Correct link must be:

```
https://example.com/subdir/3.php
```

Please tell me how to use `.htaccess` when there are two "page.php" in URLs and how to redirect it to the correct page?

Comment: That is an unusual "typo". Are you sure there isn't some other underlying issue here that results in a broken link?

Comment: Some users share wrong links...
Instead of https://example.com/subdir/3.php - they sharing https://example.com/subdir/3.php/3.php
And when user follow this link, wrong link working, but pictures not showing, navigation - same. And mostly bad thing - GoogleBot or other indexing bot scanning this page...
I need to redirect users from wrong link to the correct...
On site about 50k pages, so manually I can't do it. Thank you.

Comment: "but pictures not showing, navigation - same" - that could be caused by using relative URLs to your static resources (since the path depth is not as expected). Setting a `rel="canonical"` tag in the head section (a good practise anyway) should help resolve indexing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question...

To remove the last repeating path segment on the URL-path that looks like a `.php` file then you could do something like the following in `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove last repeating path segment that "looks like" a PHP file
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([\w-]+\.php)/\2$ /$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

This does not check whether the URL maps to an actual file, just whether it "looks like" a `.php` file.

Explanation:

- `(.+/)?` - Matches any path depth and is optional, so that we can match files in the document root. This is captured in the `$1` backreference.
- `([\w-]+\.php)` - Matches a `.php` filename. The filename can consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and/or `-`. This is captured in the `$2` backreference.
- `/\2` - matches a slash followed by a repeated filename, as matched above. `\2` is an internal backreference to the 2nd captured group.

We then redirect to `/$1$2` - which joins the URL-path and the filename together, omitting the "repeated" filename at the end of the initial request.

The above would redirect all of the following (for example):

- `/subdir/3.php/3.php` to `/subdir/3.php`
- `/index.php/index.php` to `/index.php`
- `/foo/bar/baz/test-123.php/test-123.php` to `/foo/bar/baz/test-123.php`
- `/subdir/3.php/3.php/3.php` to `/subdir/3.php/3.php` to `/subdir/3.php` (multiple redirects)

---

**UPDATE:**

> But what about random letters and numbers after / ? For example - /subdir/3.php/blala.

For a more general version that strips away everything after `.php/` in the URL you can do something like the following instead:

```
# Strip everything after what looks like a PHP file
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)/ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that these are currently 302 (temporary) redirects. You might want to consider changing these to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed they are working OK.

If you are linking to actual `.php` files, then everything after a valid file is called *additional pathname information*, or path-info (and available in the `PATH_INFO` server variable). Whether path-info is valid at all (by default) on the URL is dependent on the Apache handler (the PHP handler in this case). A URL like `/subdir/foo.html/bar`, where `foo.html` is a valid file would actually result in 404 (contrary to how PHP files are handled). You can disable path-info for PHP files as well by setting the following in your Apache config or `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

This will result is any URL that contains path-info triggering a system generated 404. Ordinarily, this is how this situation is more usually handled.

Comment: /subdir/3.php/3.php/3.php to /subdir/3.php It works, thanks!
But what about random letters and numbers after / ? For example - /subdir/3.php/blala.
If we have somepath/1.php/sometext can we redirect user to somepath/1.php without text that leads to the wrong url?
Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more general solution.

Comment: Many thanks! "AcceptPathInfo Off" - working great!
And one more thing. I seeing some links in Google Search Console and they look like this: "example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=" This part: "?_escaped_fragment_=" can it be fix with redirecting to 3.html? Thank you very much!

Comment: However, if these are real users/sites that are incorrectly backlinking to your site, as you seem to suggest, then `AcceptPathInfo Off` won't necessarily resolve that (in that it won't preserve SEO. `AcceptPathInfo Off` is intended to block automated bots and general abuse of your site - maybe that is what these links really are?

Comment: "example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=" - That is really a different question. If you ask another question and link to the new question in a comment, I'll gladly submit an answer. Thanks.

Comment: "automated bots and general abuse of your site - maybe that is what these links really are?" - probably you are right...
I've created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219593/cut-escaped-fragment-and-redirect-to-html-php please help me. Thank you.