# Cut "?_escaped_fragment_=" and redirect to html/php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I see some links in Google Search Console and they look like this:

```
example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=
```

How to cut this part: `?_escaped_fragment_=` and redirect to the current html/php file?

It should be like this:

- User enters this link: `example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=`
- and redirected to `example.com/somedir/3.html`

I found a possible way, but I can't redo it for myself... This "RewriteRule" redirecting to main page. But I don't need this feature...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1? [L,R=301]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `_escaped_fragment_` URL parameter was part of [Google's AJAX crawling specification (deprecated since Oct 2015)](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) using `#!` style URLs - so make sure your site is not making use of this still.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1? [L,R=301]
> ```

This is the right idea, in that you need to examine the value of the `QUERY_STRING` server variable, however, the target URL is possibly incorrect. (It might have been correct if you were still using this specification.)

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The above should redirect a URL of the form `example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=<anything>` to `example.com/somedir/3.html`.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is necessary to remove the query string from the target URL.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it is working OK - in order to avoid caching issues. 301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser (including any erroneous redirects).

---

> User enters this link: `example.com/somedir/3.html?_escaped_fragment_=`

Users wouldn't normally enter links like this. They shouldn't even be linked to or picked up by search engines unless there was perhaps a site-misconfiguration at some point? So, depending on how/where these URLs are being linked from (check the report in GSC) then you could even consider blocking these URLs instead? For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above would return a 403 Forbidden instead.